# Flagging off-topic should allow you to migrate to CodeReview

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129576/c-character-count

I wanted to flag this as "Move to CodeReview", but the only options were StackOverflow and Meta.

The ability to migrate code review questions from here would be really handy.

Answer (score 5):

The user [cross posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7670/c-character-count-project-euler-problem-17-wrong-answer) the question so a migration wouldn't have been a good idea.

However, Code Review as a migration target might be a good idea - if only the site were out of beta ;) Beta sites can't be the target of migrations from the dialog, it will always take a moderator to do that.

The top five migration targets in the last 90 days are:

- Stack Overflow (obviously as it's in the list)
- Super User
- User Experience
- Project Management (beta)
- Code Review (beta)

The next two live sites are:

- IT Security
- Unix and Linux.

From the numbers I'd say that there was a case for Super User and User Experience being added to the dialog.

Comment: Is this migration target data available to users or just diamond mods? I'm actually curious as to what questions are getting migrated from here to each site, rather than just what sites they are going to. I didn't see it in any of my tools, so either I missed it, it requires >20k rep, or it's a diamond mod tool.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - just diamond moderators, and in this case just the totals. I'd have to go searching to see which questions were migrated.

Comment: Too bad. That seems like interesting data to have. I wonder if it can be analyzed from the data dumps? I have a few things that I'd analyze the data dumps for, and I'd add this to the list if it was available or could be extracted some how.

Comment: @ThomasOwens It's available to all 10k+ users in the moderator tools. [Migrated stats](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats), [Migrated away](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away)

Comment: @MarkTrapp I see it. I just missed it the first time I looked.

Comment: My mistake - I forget what options are available to which level of user.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to everything [ChrisF wrote](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2827/25936), the question wasn't really on topic on CodeReview. [The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824332/c-character-count-project-euler-17-wrong-answer), the one posted on CodeReview originally, was migrated to StackOverflow, where it was closed almost immediately.

So, although the ability to migrate to sites other than StackOverflow would be handy, in this case it would have been an incorrect migration (even if it wasn't a cross post).