# How to flag off-topic to migrate to SQA

Tags: support, migration

There is a number of questions on Programmers that relate to [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com):

- [As per IEEE 12207, who has to perform SW integration testing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173165/as-per-ieee-12207-who-has-to-perform-sw-integration-testing)
- [How to apply verification and validation on the following example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/172850/how-to-apply-verification-and-validation-on-the-following-example)
- [Where should I draw the line between unit tests and integration tests? Should they be separate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171705/where-should-i-draw-the-line-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests-should-th)

How do I flag-off such topics to be migrated there?

Note: This questions is similar to another [question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/flagging-off-topic-should-allow-you-to-migrate-to-codereview) about migrations between stackexchange questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that there is now an official policy against migrating questions older than 60 days to another site:

[Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

If the question is off topic for us then it should be closed. However, note that QA questions aren't completely off topic for us, so there's no need to do anything with these.

If a question has no answers (or no upvoted answers) then I would be willing to consider migration, but it would have to be with the agreement of the moderators on QA Stack Exchange.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I can see no instrument to flag questions for migration consideration to SQA, just to StackOverflow.

Comment: @dzieciou There has to be evidence that such a link would be needed. You can however flag the question for moderator attention and we can migrate (if the target site agrees).

Comment: Thank you. I believe they would agree :-) SQA Stack Exchange sites are beta and thus fighting for traffic. Isn't migration of questions to SQA perceived here as "stealing" questions, traffic and part of the community?

Comment: @dzieciou - no.

Comment: @dzieciou Many of the sites have overlap with other sites, but the decision about where to ask the question comes down to the potential audience you are looking for answers from.  If I have a question about a database schema that would be ontopic at both Programmers and DBA, I might post at Programmers to get a wider audience or answers from a software developer persepctive. If I am looking for more specific expertise or DBA perspective then I might ask on DBA instead.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @maple_shaft That makes sense. Testing is activity of both testers and programmers, but they have different perspective, often test on different levels (integration vs. unit), etc. SQA seems more for testers, including those that automate tests.

Comment: @ChrisF - just to note, all three questions are pretty new (last few days) so the 60 day rule wouldn't come into play yet

Comment: As a moderator of SQA, obviously I have an interest in seeing it grow. But my first priority is to getting problems people face solved. Migrating for the sake of migration or to bolster SQA would both, in my opinion, be bad. I agree with Chris's perspective of "If there's no quality answers coming in, migrate it." I would take it further and say that experienced users who know that questions of that nature have been migrated, then migrate those too. The sooner a question is in a spot where it gets properly answered, the better. But if it's already in that spot, it doesn't *need* to move.

Comment: @corsiKa, I agree. Migrating poor questions is like hiding the trashes under the carpet. But how do you know whether the question is in the right spot? The fact it has not get any answer at ProgrammableWeb does not mean it will get one on SQA. On the other side, you may not know whether it will get more attention on SQA until you migrate it there. Each site may have a different visitors.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who'se been involved on those threads, I'd like to make a couple of comments

- Firstly, I wasn't even aware of SQA.SE - I'll have to have a look see!
- I believe there is a general policy of not migrating questions to sites still in *Beta*
- Whilst the questions may be **MORE** on-topic at SQA.SE they are still on-topic at P.SE

ISO/IEC (IEEE) 12207 is a software development lifecycle standard, not just a software quality assurance standard - and because of the overlap between sites, the questions are relevant and on-topic at P.SE as well as SQA.SE (and probably SO.SE)... so migration is not appropriate.

Now, off to nosey around SQA.SE

Comment: As an aside, I've found NO questions relating to ISO12207 on SQA