# New Site Name and Help Center: Phase I Complete

Tags: discussion, help-center, new-site-name

Previous Discussion: [Follow-Up 3: New Site Name and Help Center Discussions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/follow-up-3-new-site-name-and-help-center-discussions)

---

After approval from [Ana](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106878/ana), I published the discussed updates to the [Help Center's /help/on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [site's /tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour). In the near future, we should be hearing from her about the timeline of the technical implementation for changing our site's name and domain.

Please leave any feedback here about these changes.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: The Help/About page looks fantastic, Thomas.

Comment: bullets in "poor fit" section don't refer meta guidance, is this intended? In the past we made such bullets linked per [Help Center tuning: “help/on-topic/and it is not about…” += references to meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7236/31260)

Comment: Very good!  (Just found a typo on the site's tour page, in the second line of the initial paragraph, I am sure you find it by yourself, too ;-).

Comment: Thomas, I want to request that after site rename and respective URLs change SE team would configure [one-flag removal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773) for Stack Overflow comments containing ["programmers.stackexchange"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20298/dugas-playground "archive of such comments for those interested in details"). Would an answer here be an appropriate place for such a request?

Comment: @DocBrown Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @gnat (1) Yeah. I missed that. I think I had two tabs open. I'll fix that at some point today. (2) I'd bring that up on Meta.SO after the change, since it's a change to a feature on that site. Plus, it may give some more visibility to us and our new name/clarified scope.

Comment: [my past experience at Math meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260) suggests that requesting this at MSO may be a risky venture. :) But your point about giving more visibility sounds too tempting, guess I'll give it a go

Comment: @gnat I can post it if you'd like me to, but if you want a change for a given site, it should be requested where those people frequent.

Comment: you posting this instead of me sounds like the way to go, it will likely add authority to this request since you're site moderator. I will ping you in case if I figure a reason why it could be better for me to post but this is very unlikely, everything seems to be in favor of you doing this

Comment: `, and maintaining software responsibly.` I can't tell you how much I love the use of the word "responsibly" here.  The importance of "ethics" in an engineering discipline cannot be overstated. I am super excited for the site and am proud to be a part of this.  Thank you everybody for helping make this site a unique and useful part of the Internet!

Comment: Wanted y'all to know I'm still working with folks on the inside to get you a timeline for the remaining changes. No news just yet, but I'm on it!

Comment: @Ana The silence is deafening.

Comment: Just a note, we're sorry that we haven't been able to get definite dates, this is a priority for us that happened to land in the middle of some engineering organizational restructuring (hence the delay). I'll make sure the information is flowing by next week :)

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 10):

In ["follow up 2" discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8114/31260) the plan seemed to be that we are going to have words

> ### not code troubleshooting

in the site tagline, looking about like that:

[image: proposed intro image]

Is this still the plan?

Comment: Yes, but that tagline isn't mod editable that I can see.

Comment: yes @Thomas I know it's only dev editable, just wanted to make sure if the plan still stands

Comment: Excuse me for being daft, but what is a Systems Development Life Cycle and what has it got to do with software engineering?

Comment: @oals see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8114/31260

Comment: @ThomasOwens from what I see at [SE sites list](http://stackexchange.com/sites) it looks like plan has changed somewhere along the way, and the words about code troubleshooting were lost ([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTVR.png)). This is full text now: _"Q&A for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly"_

Comment: @gnat Please post that [here](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/its-official-this-site-is-now-software-engineering-stack-exchange)

Comment: @ThomasOwens there you go - [posted to where you asked](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8272/31260)